# iOS: Handle touches event in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have implemented WKWebView in my view and loading html, css and js from local file. some pages have link and youtube video. The question is how to handle touch event when clicking in page beyond links and Youtubes...?

Comment: Have you already tried to achieve it somehow (e.g. [handling touches for UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130641/1492173))?

Comment: Of course UIView no problem. I can handle it but for WKWebView you can imagine you have links, a youtube video embedded in your page and .... and you wanna inspect if user tap on Links or youtube video or on content of page.

Comment: Try to look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790298/how-to-capture-taps-ignored-by-wkwebview/40424850#40424850